# using dateInput as the date component of a url to scrape from

Tags: r, xml, shiny, shinydashboard

My goal is a Shiny app that scrapes and plots html table data by user-selected date. For each day of data there's conveniently one webpage to scrape with each date having its own url ending in `yyyymmdd`, eg:

`http://cdec.water.ca.gov/reportapp/javareports?name=PAGE6.20191219` 
`http://cdec.water.ca.gov/reportapp/javareports?name=PAGE6.20191216`

Once the user selects or changes the date, I want the app to build the url and then scrape and visualize the day of data.  The scraping/visualizing part works, but only when I explicitly define the whole url. So I'm stuck on the first part, defining the url - trying to paste the user input date (eg `20191219`) to the end of the url beginning (always `http://cdec.water.ca.gov/reportapp/javareports?name=PAGE6.`).

With what I have:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)
library(XML)

ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(),
dashboardSidebar(

dateInput('date',
          label = 'cdec query date:', format = "yyyymmdd",
          value = "2019-12-16" )
          ),

dashboardBody(
tags$style(type = "text/css", "#mapplot {height: calc(100vh - 80px) !important;}"),
leafletOutput("mapplot"),
useShinyjs() ) )

server <- function(input, output) {
 addClass(selector = "body")
 options(shiny.maxRequestSize=225*1024^2)

baseurl <- "http://cdec.water.ca.gov/reportapp/javareports?name=PAGE6."

# append the user-entered yyyymmdd to the base url
url <- reactive({paste0(baseurl, input$date) })

# scrape data
cdec_swe_table  <- readHTMLTable(url)

# process/tidy/format cdec_swe_table and display results on map
# eg, cdec_swe_table <- cdec_swe_table %>% mutate, filter etc, then st_as_sf() to create spatial object
# all processing/mapping works outside of shiny,
# it's the reactive wrapping (which wrapper(s), how many, where) around
# url/cdec_swe_table I'm missing

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I get:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘readHTMLTable’ for 
signature ‘"reactiveExpr"’
```

I think I'm missing some reactivity fundamentals. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: change `cdec_swe_table  <- readHTMLTable(url)` to something along `observe(print(readHTMLTable(url())))`. Explanation: you defined url as an interactive expression, therefore you have to access it with `url()` und evaluate it in a reactive context,...e.g. with observe,...

Comment: thank you. I don't get an error above but with my case, with `cdec_swe_table <- observe(print(readHTMLTable(url())))`:`Error in $.shinyoutput(output, value) : 
  Reading objects from shinyoutput object not allowed`, somewhere from the next steps that redefine `cdec_swe_table` as it's cleaned up.

Comment: Assigning observe to a variable will likely not work. And to be precise not the replacement I suggested ;) if you want to assign to a variable do that within observe. Maybe some tutorials concerning reactive/observe etc. Will help as well.

Comment: Try wrapping input in `reactive` first, then `paste0` with `format` to render as string without hyphens: `dt <- reactive({ input$date }); url <- paste0(baseurl, format(dt(), "yyyymmdd"))`

Comment: thank you. I tried just that (all within the server block) but get `Operation not allowed without an active reactive context`